# Regex on key value pair

Tags: groovy

If I get a string in a payload with key values as 'listed' or a string that starts with 'fun' and ends with 'place' or 'num' I have to use the list below and output with the value 'Not_listed', 'Num' or 'FunPlace'. Is there a way to accomplish this using Regex in groovy?

```
regex={'listed|^other|unknown','Not_listed'
       'num', 'Num',
        'test', 'Test', 
       'fun.*place|funplace':'FunPlace'}
```

Comment: Is it the case that if the input is `"listed"`, the result should be `"Not_listed"`?

Comment: The requirements are not clear to me.  Does something like https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/688799c622df993b28a0a6c4e3cc7a12 help?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yes

Comment: The case statement you have provided helps, but I have a key-value regex list of 40, so wondering if there is a better solution...

Comment: "but I have a key-value regex list of 40" - I misunderstood the question.  Apologies.

Comment: Is it the case that the comma before 'Not_listed', 'Num' and 'Test' are supposed to be colons and then every key in the payload represents a regex and if that regex matches a piece of input then the value associated with that key should be returned?

Comment: You are right @JeffScottBrown

Comment: "You are right @JeffScottBrown" - You should fix the mistakes in the question.  The mistakes make it more difficult to make sense of the question, IMO.

Comment: I put it the right way and the moderator changed the regex part.. not sure why.. Anyway found the solution. Thanks @JeffScottBrown

Answer (score 1):

```
def test='fun XYZ place'

def regex=[
  'listed|^other|unknown':'Not_listed',
  'num': 'Num',
  'test': 'Test', 
  'fun.*place|funplace':'FunPlace'
]

def result = regex.find{k,v-> test=~k}?.value
```

Comment: I think `test==~k` may make more sense than `test=~k`.  In this context I think they will yield the same result but you don't really need to retrieve the Matcher and then subject it to Groovy truth.  `==~` I think expresses the intent.

Comment: That worked with one fix ?.getValue() Thank you guys for helping!

Comment: I am a little surprised that `?.value` didn't work.